# Add custom class to a particular menu

Tags: 6, routes, theming

I need to know how to add extra class to a perticular menu.For example i have custom menu "menu-header-let",This menu is rendering like below,

```
<ul class="menu"><li class="leaf first"><a title="Redirecting to Help Page" href="/vsv/content1">Help</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a title="" href="/vsv/content1">Home</a></li>
<li class="leaf last"><a title="" href="/vsv/content1">home2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now i want add extra class to the ul like below

```
   <ul class="header-top-menu">
```

I used phptemplate_menu_tree(), but i need different class for each custom menu.If is override menu theme and adding same class for all custom menu.

I have no idea how to add different class when different custom menu renders in drupal.

please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the code in [tutorial](http://programmingbulls.com/complete-drupal-6-menu-theming) that **beth** mentioned has bugs and does not work. The best solution I've found up to now is this:

```
<?php
function YOUR_THEME_menu_tree($tree) {
  if (preg_match('/A unique string in your menu/', $tree)) {
      return '<ul class="header-top-menu">' . $tree . '</ul>';
  } else {
    return '<ul class="menu">'. $tree .'</ul>';
  } 
}
?>
```

You can use any unique path or link title as string to identify the menu. This solution was inspired by a comment in the cited tutorial.

Comment: You're right, the tutorial contains an infinite loop (see [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53809/compare-two-menu-tree-objects)).

Answer (score 0):

There's a tutorial just for you: http://programmingbulls.com/complete-drupal-6-menu-theming

Answer (score 0):

I should agree that theming of menu items in Drupal sucks.

There is a module [Menu Attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) which does just that. You can also add `Id,Name, Target, Rel,Class,Style,Accesskey` attributes to the particular menus.