# Compare two menu tree objects

Tags: 6, routes

I'm trying to add custom css class to a particular menu, same task [mentioned here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/27110/7698).

I moved a little further and found [this article](http://programmingbulls.com/complete-drupal-6-menu-theming). So I put following code in template.php:

```
<?php
function phptemplate_menu_tree($tree) {
  if ($tree == menu_tree()) {
    $output .= "<ul id=\"foo\" class=\"bar\">";
    $output .= $tree;
    $output .= "</ul>\n";
    return $output;
 } else {
  return '<ul class="menu">'. $tree .'</ul>';

 }
}
?>
```

but constantly getting 502 error when trying to compare `$tree` and `menu_tree()`.

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I've fixed the initial issue in the question and posted the solution [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/53929/7698). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call [`menu_tree()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree/6) from within [`theme_menu_tree()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/6) because `menu_tree()` contains a call to `theme_menu_tree()`. Your code contains an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for reply, however menu_tree() in D6 has default argument 'navigation', and that is the one I need to customize.

Comment: Attempting to run `menu_tree()` without passing parameters yields a log message, "call_user_func_array() [<a href='function.call-user-func-array'>function.call-user-func-array</a>]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'garland_menu_tree' was given in /includes/theme.inc on line 656." I think `menu_tree()` is failing and parameters are the issue.

Comment: Further debugging indicates that [`theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/6) is failing because it doesn't like something about the hook parameter.

Comment: I was partly correct. Edited answer.